# Automatically block IP in apache2 - it is possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, blocking, ip-blocking, ip-banning

Is there are a way to automatically block IPs with apache2. For example, if we get a lot requests (100s) for non-existing pages (or known patterns, like CHANGE_LIST.txt, etc.) to block that IP and add it to deny list.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which can be made to monitor Apache log files for requests such as you have described and then execute some action when a threshold is reached.  That action may modify your local firewall configuration to block the requestor, or perform some other action to cause Apache to reject the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mod_evasive? It may be exactly what you are looking for, depending on the block time you want.